# Can we pass custom values using square connect and have it returned back in webhook notification

Tags: square-connect

I am looking for information on how to pass a custom variable (transaction_logID) to the square API and then have it returned back to me on the webhooks notification URL response.

How can i specifically link a "charge" event with a "notification" event so that I can update my personal SQL record with the transaction result? (Approved, Declined etc)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately passing in custom data and getting it back in a webhook isn't possible.

Depending on what exactly you want to link your notification to, you can look up the ID from the webhook in the v1 payments endpoints.